# Why does NSMutableArray have duplicate objects?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have some code that creates a string and adds that string to a mutable array.  Here is the code:

```
    ExportBookData *abe = [[ExportBookData alloc] initWithCategory:@"ABE"];
    abe.builtFileList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 2];
    abe.exportData = [NSMutableArray array];  

        for(int i = 0; i < booksArray.count; i++)  {
        [tabString setString: @""];  //   clear it...
        [tabString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t"
                                 "%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\n",

                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] sku],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] title],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] author],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] illustrator],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] price],
                                 [(Books *)[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] quantity],
                                 @"Book",  //  book type
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] bookDescription],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] binding],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] bookCondition],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] pubName],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i]pubLocation ],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] pubYear],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] isbn],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] primaryCatalog],
                                 @"",@"",  //  seller catalogs  secondary and third catalog entries (not used)
                                 @"",  //  ABE category    <----- TODO
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] keywords],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] jacket],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] edition],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] printing],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] signedBy],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i]volume],
                                 [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] bookSize],
                                 @""  //  image url
                                 ]];

        NSLog(@"\n\ntabString: %@",tabString);

        [abe.exportData addObject: tabString];  //  add to array

        NSLog(@"\n\nexportData: %@", abe.exportData);  //  <-------------- overwritten with last entry, so all entries are the same  TODO
    }
```

*booksArray* is a NSMutableArray which is filled by reading a CoreData store; *exportData* is also a NSMutableArray.  The data in *booksArray* is valid, with a count of 2;  the data in tabString is also valid, containing the correct line from *booksArray*.  The line

```
[abe.exportData addObject: tabString];
```

has a duplication of the last record in *booksArray*.  This is the output from the log methods:

```
---->booksArray.count: 2

tabString: 120  Women Who Run With The Wolves:  Myths And Stories Of The Wild Woman Archetype   Clarissa Pinkola Estes      2.1 1   Book        Hardcover       Ballantine Books        1992    0345377443                      Like New        (null)              

exportData: (
"120\tWomen Who Run With The Wolves:  Myths And Stories Of The Wild Woman Archetype\tClarissa Pinkola Estes\t\t2.1\t1\tBook\t\tHardcover\t\tBallantine Books\t\t1992\t0345377443\t\t\t\t\t\tLike New\t\t(null)\t\t\t\t\n"
)

tabString: 121  Colossus: The Secrets Of Bletchley Park's Code-breaking Computers   B. Jack Copeland        35  1   Book        Paperback (Reprint)     Oxford University Press, USA        2010    9780199578146                       No Dust Jacket      (null)              

exportData: (
"121\tColossus: The Secrets Of Bletchley Park's Code-breaking Computers\tB. Jack Copeland\t\t35\t1\tBook\t\tPaperback (Reprint)\t\tOxford University Press, USA\t\t2010\t9780199578146\t\t\t\t\t\tNo Dust Jacket\t\t(null)\t\t\t\t\n",
"121\tColossus: The Secrets Of Bletchley Park's Code-breaking Computers\tB. Jack Copeland\t\t35\t1\tBook\t\tPaperback (Reprint)\t\tOxford University Press, USA\t\t2010\t9780199578146\t\t\t\t\t\tNo Dust Jacket\t\t(null)\t\t\t\t\n"
)
```

I have looked and looked (Google, SO) for several hours now, and I am doing everything correctly, from what I see in other question's answers, and I don't see what could possibly cause this.  Help would greatly be appreciated.  SD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tabString` appears to be an `NSMutableString` that you attempt to use over and over. That doesn't work. You end up added the same mutable string to the array multiple times. Just assign the `stringWithFormat` to a normal, local `NSString`.

And why call `[booksArray objectAtIndex:i]` over and over and over? Get the object once. Better yet, use fast enumeration in your loop.

```
for (YourBookClass *book in booksArray) {
    NSString *tabString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t"
                             "%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@\n",
       book.sku,
       book.title,
       // and all of the rest of the properties
       ]];

    [abe.exportData addObject:tabString];
}
```

Also keep in mind that your code will generate an invalid CSV file if any the values contain a tab or newline character. Such values need to be put into quotes.

Comment: Hi Rick... yep, the tabString is indeed mutable... RATS!  Thanks again for coming to my aid... SD